# Ansible: redownload archive only if src has been changed

Tags: ansible

I have the following task:

```
- name: Download foobar tool
  unarchive:
    src: https://github.com/foobar/releases/download/v1.0/foobar.zip
    dest: /usr/local/bin/
    remote_src: yes
    creates: /usr/local/bin/foobar
```

When a new version of `foobar` is released, I want to update it, so I change the `src`:

```
- name: Download foobar tool
  unarchive:
    src: https://github.com/foobar/releases/download/v2.0/foobar.zip
    dest: /usr/local/bin/
    remote_src: yes
    creates: /usr/local/bin/foobar
```

The issue is, since `/usr/local/bin/foobar` already exists, Ansible won't run the task. I can remove the `creates` option, but downloading the same archive every time the playbook runs doesn't feel right.

Is there a way to download the archive only when `src` is changed?

Comment: unarchive module doesn't support md5 check.  You can split the task Into 2 steps with get_url module.

Comment: Ideally some like `/usr/local/bin/foobar --version` would output something which could be used with a conditional for the unarchive task. If that is not a option I would store the version in a file on the host and create a conditional based on that.

Comment: How about `creates: /usr/local/bin/foobar-{{ version }}` and then symlink `foobar` to `foobar-{{ version }}`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. I asume, you mean with "changed", that the content changes and not the version. In case of versioning I would say - use 'get_url' and define the correct version in the destination filename.

First - you should use get_url to download the file itself and store the last-modified header from the server somwhere on the destination. This information should be idempotent. Then you can make a HEAD request to the new URL to find out, if this timestamp is different and download the file only when the timestamp differs.

Second - most repositories also store the SHA etc. checksum. You can also use that file (download it always) and compare it.

Third - you could also just store the URL and check, if it changes and only download the file (asuming your example really means the same file should be replaced).